# PHP script via JS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, geolocation, currency

I'm trying to load a php script via JS to be able to locate users and display the currency that corresponds to their location. I'm calling the php script as so:

```
 function determineCurrency() {
     $.get('/myscript.php').then(function (data) {
         //... code for changing currency
    }}

 }
```

The code that changes currency is within the determineCurrency function, using the geoplugin being called.

Here's the contents of the php script:

```
<?php
$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
$city = $geo["geoplugin_city"];
?>
```

There's no error, but the code is not changing the currency.

Comment: you are not echoing or returning anything from php. Also where is your ajax call?

Comment: It should return some value which you can retrieve in ajax response

Answer (score 2):

You are not echoing or returning anything. Try this and then process your ajax `success()`:

```
<?php
    $user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
    $arr = [
        'user_ip' => $user_ip,
        'geo' => $geo,
        'country' => $geo["geoplugin_countryName"],
        'city' => $geo["geoplugin_city"]
    ];
    echo json_encode ($arr);
    ?>
```